# Livewire - Change follow button to unfollow once clicked(persist) without reloading the page. vice versa

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

As the title says. Is this possible for `livewire`? I have a piece of code that enables user to follow an author and unfollow using form post which reloads the page after clicking the button. But I am thinking to make it have a better UX by using `livewire`.

FollowButton.php

```
class FollowButton extends Component
{
    public $postAuthorId;
    public $authorName;
    public $isFollowed;
    public Post $post;
    public Follow $follow;


    public function mount(){

        $this->postAuthorId = $this->post->author->id;
        $this->authorName = $this->post->author->name;
        $this->isFollowed = (bool) $this->post->author->followedBy(auth()->user());
    }

    public function follow()
    {

        Follow::create([
            'user_id' => $this->postAuthorId,
            'follower_id' => auth()->id()
        ]);;

        session()->flash('success', 'Followed' . $this->authorName);

    }

    public function unfollow()
    {

        # code here..
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.follow-button');
    }
}
```

follow-button.blade.php

```
<div>
    
    @if(!$isFollowed)
    
                <button wire:click="follow" class="btn btn-default">
                    Follow
                </button>
    
            @else
    
                <button wire:click="unfollow" class="btn btn-default">
                    Unfollow
                </button>
    
            @endif
      
    </div>
```

Then in my card.blade.php

```
@livewire('follow-button', ['post' => $post])
```

Comment: Are you using livewire in that app? Show us your code.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai  I am trying to do follow and unfollow button. which changes realtime wihtout reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the property `isFollowed` on mount method it wont run on every request. Mount method will only run while mounting the component into page.

So inside the `follow` method you need to refresh the property

```
public function follow()
{

    Follow::create([
        'user_id' => $this->postAuthorId,
        'follower_id' => auth()->id()
    ]);
    $this->isFollowed = (bool) true;


    session()->flash('success', 'Followed' . $this->authorName);

}

public function unfollow()
{
    Follow::query()
->where([
    [
        'user_id', '=', $this->postAuthorId,
    ],
    [
        'follower_id', '=', auth()->id()
    ]
])
->delete();
    $this->isFollowed = (bool) false;


    session()->flash('success', 'Followed' . $this->authorName);

}
```

Comment: Should I do the same as to the unfollow method? This works button changed to unfollow. But unfollowing doesn't work using this same scenario

Comment: yes you need to do on both the actions

Comment: Or maybe extract into a method and call it on both actions

Comment: You can probably assume that if the `Follow` model was created correctly before, that inside the `follow()` method you can just do `$this->isFollowed = true;`, so you don't query the database again. Same but inverted on unfollow, set it to false if the removal of `Follow` was without errors.